# Target 'Search' in Whole Page

Tags: php, javascript, html, search

I want my search bar to complete a search, however, I want the target to be 'wholepage' and not to totally move to another page?

```
<div id="search_anything"> 
    <form action="/search.php" method="get" id='searchForm'> 
        <div class="searchFormDiv"> 
            <input type="text" name="search" value="Search Mail..." id="search" onfocus="if( $(this).attr('value').indexOf('...') >= 0) $(this).attr('value',''); $(this).select();" /> 
        </div> 
    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to search and display the results on the same page instead of redirecting to another page to display the results?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="get" id='searchForm'>
```

Don't forget that most of the time you need to process the form on the same page too (or include a separate form processor script on that page).

For example if you want to process the form with another PHP file, you can paste this anywhere above the form:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['search'])) include 'formprocessor.php'; ?>
```

Comment: When I enter that code I get the following link: - http://liveternet.com/?search=(My search), however, I want: http://liveternet.com/search.php?search=(My Search) << including the search being complete in the same webpage :) (and not redirected to another)

Comment: @user686512 Why do you want **search.php** in the action attribute when you do not want to redirect to search.php? With **liveternet.com/?search=mysearch** you will be able to process the form on the same page. If you really want both, you can do some rewriting with Apache's mod_rewrite (in a .htaccess file).

Answer (score 0):

When I enter that code I get the following link: - liveternet.com/?search=(My search), however, I want: liveternet.com/search.php?search=(My Search) << including the search being complete in the same webpage :) (and not redirected to another)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.post(
    'do_query.php',         // File with query
    { num: '1', str: 'string' },    // Vars passed as post
    function(responseText){     // Callback
        $('#your_div').html(responseText); // Load content results from do_query page.
    },
    "html"              // Set type as html
);
    preventDefault();           // Prevent form from submiting
});
```

This should work. Please give feedback.

Comment: Why are you placing a PHP block inside a piece of JavaScript? Besides that it won't work with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Edited. Now using an ajax request instead.